# Cannot Publish Encoded Asset in Azure Media Services

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-media-services

I'm having a problem publishing an encoded asset in Azure Media Services.

I can see that my asset is being created and encoded because it displays in my Media Services account but the "publish" functionality fails. I can successfully publish any asset that is created and encoded by my application, by hitting the publish button in the portal. However, I need to be able to do it programmatically. This is my method. I don't get any errors...

```
   `private static IAsset PublishAsset(IJob job)
    {
        var preparedAsset = job.OutputMediaAssets.FirstOrDefault();
        var ismAssetFiles = preparedAsset.AssetFiles.ToList().
          Where(f => f.Name.EndsWith(".ism", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
          .ToArray();

        ismAssetFiles.First().IsPrimary = true;
        ismAssetFiles.First().Update();
        return preparedAsset;

    }`
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pasted code does not publish the asset but only mark the .ism file as primary file in the asset.

To publish the asset, you should create an access locator as explained here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-dotnet-get-started/#publish-the-asset-and-get-urls-for-streaming-and-progressive-download

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that but I will try again. I'm completely new to Azure so I figure most issues are due to gaps in my understanding, at this point.

Comment: Just to clarify, it this the way to publish an already encoded media file? 

My encoding piece is working fine. I just end up with an unpublished asset in Media Services. If I hit the "Publish" button in the portal it creates a url. For example, 

https://whatever.blob.core.windows.net/asset-904e82a9-c277-45cd-aa88-071948c39fd8/Video1_H264_2200kbps_AAC_und_ch2_128kbps.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&sr=c&si=a6ae677a-f83f-4233-af76-0ac3e438dccc&sig=d68NnWBHO8Vie8zBhKZfk4zMswmRZgzS3pe7eonn2ZE%3D&st=2016-04-25T03%3A17%3A22Z&se=2116-04-01T03%3A17%3A22Z 

I can then embed this successfully.

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I already had an access locator set up. The problem was I was looking for an asset file with the extension of the file *before* it was encoded.

`var streamingAssetFile = assetFiles.Where(f => f.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".wmv")).FirstOrDefault();`

Obviously it couldn't find an asset with that extension anymore, so it just didn't publish. I changed it to look for .mp4 and now it works fine.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct because it did lead me to my rookie error. :-D

Comment: Ok great ! Happy to help.